# Element has no outerwidth?

Tags: javascript, jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/gregborbonus/mu1jn6vx/

Can anyone tell me why the first child(an A tag) logs as null?

This line: `console.log($(this).children().first().outerWidth());`

Comment: console.log($(this).outerWidth()); ? You are targeting 'a' in each() loop, right?

Comment: yeah, overlooked it. Sometimes you're looking for something so complex when it's so simple, it escapes you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @nevermind hinted at, the reason is that you're inside an `each` function so the reference to `this` is not what you are expecting. Since you are already inside of the `each` loop `this` is already referencing the current element, so you can take out the `children('a')` because you are already referencing the `a` element.

https://jsfiddle.net/mu1jn6vx/1/

That is why you were getting null, because the `a` element has no children of type `a`. See fiddle.

Comment: Must have been tired, didn't even realize something so simple.